# Adding params to route model breaks ArrayController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Since adding a param to our route's model, we can no longer add new items in our Documents ArrayController:

Old Route:

```
model: function(params) { 
        return this.store.find('document');
}
```

New Route:

```
queryParams: {
    owner: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
},
model: function(params) { 
        var ownerID = this.get('ownerID')
        return this.store.find('document', {owner : ownerID});
}
```

ArrayController:

```
actions: {
      addItem: function() {
      this.store.createRecord('document');
}
```

The code still loads the documents, but when the addItem action is called, the newly created record is not added to the ArrayController's content. In the old code, clicking addItem immediately added a new document to those on screen. I have confirmed that the server is returning an array, so am not sure why new documents can no longer be added. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Background**
The setup is that a user has documents,but can also view documents of other users. This is the reason why we need to dynamically change the ownerID in the url of documents so we can easily display documents belonging to a specific user.

Comment: Does using `store.filter()` work? http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter It seems like it may have a better chance of staying up to date as records are added/removed.

Comment: @c4p I have tried store.filter, but then the initial call to the server to fetch the documents is not made when transitioning into the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find by query (which is what `find('foo', {bar:'baz'})` is not a live record set.  It only shows the records which were returned by the call to the server.

When you create a new record client side, Ember doesn't know whether or not that server side criteria matches.  You either need to use `filter` with server side and client side criteria (which will make a call to the server and also keep filtering all client side records by the client side filter)

```
this.store.filter('documents', {document : 'asdf'}, function(record){
  return record.get('title') == 'So I Married an Axe Murderer';
});
```

or if you just want it to always show all client side records you can do this

```
// make the call
model: function(params){
  this.store.find('document', {owner : params.ownerID});
  return this.store.all('document');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer and explanation.